# Swift Contact Picker Detail View

Tags: xcode, swift, contactpicker

I have been working on this for many days with no luck!

I would like to use Contact Picker to go directly to the detail page of a contact so that I can choose a mobile number or email address from the list. I have managed to use predicate to fetch contact details but as these may be stored differently e.g. work email / home email etc I found that my only solution is to allow the user to click on the correct field. Is this possible? In short I want to go directly to the page of "John Appleseed" and then retrieve what I click on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no delegate for something like that. You need create your own custom views with the information you fetched and ask the user to select one of those information.

From iOS 9 you can use [CNContextPickerViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactsUI/Reference/CNContactPickerViewController_Class/), but it will only allow you to select a contact, not a single contact detail. You still need to handle that yourself.